# Q: golang pointer to map[string]interface{}

Tags: json, pointers, dictionary, go, interface

I (golang newbie) am trying to create a map[string]interfaces{} in a function. The code compiles and runs but the map is empty.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"   
    "encoding/json" 
)


func main() {
    var f interface{}
    var sJson string                    // JSON string from VT
    var err error                       // errors
    var b []byte                        // bytearray of JSON string
    var rootMap map[string]interface{}

    rootMap = make(map[string]interface{})

    sJson=`{"key": "foo"}`

    fmt.Println(sJson)

    err = json2map(&b, &sJson, f, rootMap)

    if err != nil { return }

    switch v := rootMap["key"].(type) {
        case float64:
            fmt.Printf("Value: %d",v)
        case string:
            fmt.Printf("Value: %s", v)
        case nil:
            fmt.Println("key is nil")           
        default:
            fmt.Println("type is unknown")          
    }       
}

func json2map(b *[]byte, sJson *string, f interface{}, myMap map[string]interface{}) error {
    var err error
    *b = []byte(*sJson) 
    err = json.Unmarshal(*b,&f) 
    myMap = f.(map[string]interface{})
    return err
}
```

The output is:

```
{"key": "foo"}
key is nil
```

I found [this article](http://www.goinggo.net/2013/07/understanding-pointers-and-memory.html) which describes how to use map[string]string. This code works as expected:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type MyType struct {
    Value1 int
    Value2 string
}

func main() {
    myMap := make(map[string]string)
    myMap["key"] = "foo"
    ChangeMyMap(myMap)  
    fmt.Printf("Value : %s\n",  myMap["key"])    
}

func ChangeMyMap(TheMap map[string]string) {
    TheMap["key"] = "bar"
}
```

So I think my problem has to do with the map being of type interface instead of string but I cannot tell why the first code doesn't work, while the 2nd does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a number of things causing confusion here:

- You don't need `b` at all. You're passing a pointer to a byte slice that you're reassigning inside the function. Just use the string directly.
- There's no need to us a pointer to the `sJson` string. Strings are immutable, and you're not trying to reassign the `sJson` variable.
- You're unmarshaling into an empty interface, and then trying to reassign the `myMap` variable to the contents of `f`. Since `myMap` isn't a pointer, that assignment is only scoped to within the function. Just unmarshal directly into `myMap`

If you change those things, you'll find the `json2map` function ends up being one line, and can be dropped altogether:

```
func json2map(sJson string, myMap map[string]interface{}) error {
    return json.Unmarshal([]byte(sJson), &myMap)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! That helped me solve the problem! (However, I still don't understand why my other code did not work, but I hope I'll understand that once I'm not that much of a newbie in golang anymore.)

Comment: @user208383: You seem to be stumbling on how pointers work more than Go specifically. Try working through the [Tour Of Go](http://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) which has examples that might be of help to you.